# Disable different checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, function, checkbox

Currently what I'm doing is if I check the checkbox it will disabled it and change the words to green. but however I'm doing it with ID. How do I go about doing this for multiple checkbox.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
    if($('#1').is(":checked")){
        $('#1').parent().addClass("Green");
        Enable = true;
    }
    if(Enable == true) {
        $('#1').prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: do you mean ``$(this)`` ?

Comment: if you disable it, how would the user uncheck it, if it were a mistake?

Comment: Instead of specify element id $("#1"). use $(this)

Comment: oh I'm trying to do something like a checklist. So if the first checkbox is done. the user will tick it and it will turn green.(also disabling it). I want the function to be applied to all the checkbox but I'm not too sure how to go about writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for referring to the appropriate checkbox, and add the var keyword to the enable variable, so it would be local to the function:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(this).parent().addClass("Green");
                var enable = true;
            }
            if(enable == true) {
                $(this).prop("checked", "checked");
            }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/er144/MTAw2/

Answer (score 1):

Just try this.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).parent().addClass("Green");
        Enable = true;
    }
    if(Enable == true) {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the clicked checkbox , use..

```
$(this).prop("disabled", true);
```